# How to define entity property with list of values

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I have a **consult_status** property for my Consults entity. As defined in the model:

```
consult_status = ndb.StringProperty() # Consult status: (Pending, Completed, Cancelled)
```

As seen in the comment my status can have one of three values. I believe rather than using StringProperty I should be using a list? How do I define this in my model instead of using string? Is this where repeated=true is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `repeated=true` is for properties which can have **simultaneously** multiple values.

For your use case you're looking for the `choices` option. From the [Property Options](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/entity-property-reference#options) table:

> **choices**
>
> List of values of underlying type
>
> Optional list of allowable values.

You'd still be using a `StringProperty`.